# Upload de múltiplos arquivos usando o Uploadfy em ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, html5, upload

Como implementar o upload de múltiplos arquivos com o `uploadf`? Acho muito interessante usar as barras de upload etc.

está dando este erro:
[image]

Este é meu controller:
[image]

Podem notar que tem muitas mensagens de erro também.

Código da View:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('#file_upload').uploadify({
            'swf': "@Url.Content("~/Content/UploadifyContent/uploadify.swf")",
            'cancelImg': "@Url.Content("~/Content/UploadifyContent/uploadify-cancel.png")",
            'uploader': "@Url.Action("Upload", "Photo")",            
            'buttonText': 'SELECIONAR',
            'onUploadSuccess': function (file, data, response) {
                $("#uploaded").append("<img src='" + data + "' alt='Uploaded Image' />");
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A resposta original recomendava utilizar o pacote NuGet:

https://www.nuget.org/packages/Uploadfy/

Mas ele é antigo e pode não servir se a versão do jQuery for das mais recentes. Então faça o download do Zip neste endereço:

http://www.uploadify.com/download/

Coloque os arquivos no seu projeto da seguinte forma:

- `~/Scripts/jquery.uploadify.js`
- `~/Content/UploadifyContent/uploadify.swf`
- `~/Content/UploadifyContent/uploadify-cancel.png`
- `~/Content/UploadifyContent/uploadify.css`

### Exemplo de View

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Upload Files</title>
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    <script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.uploadify.js")"></script>       
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="@Url.Content("~/Content/UploadifyContent/uploadify.css")" />

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $('#file_upload').uploadify({
                'swf': "@Url.Content("~/Content/UploadifyContent/uploadify.swf")",
                'cancelImg': "@Url.Content("~/Content/UploadifyContent/uploadify-cancel.png")",
                'uploader': "@Url.Action("Upload", "Home")",
                'onUploadSuccess' : function(file, data, response) {
                     $("#uploaded").append("<img src='" + data + "' alt='Uploaded Image' />");
                }
            });
        });
    </script>

</head>
<body>
    <div>
        Click Select files to upload files.
        <input type="file" name="file_upload" id="file_upload" />
    </div>
    <div id="uploaded">
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

### Exemplo de Controller (Controllers\HomeController.cs)

```cs
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return View();
}

public ActionResult Upload()
{
    var file = Request.Files["Filedata"];
    string savePath = Server.MapPath(@"~\Content\" + file.FileName);
    file.SaveAs(savePath);

    return Content(Url.Content(@"~\Content\" + file.FileName));
}
```

Comment: Fiz tudo isso e nada... Não consigo instalar o package pois a versão do jQuery usada no pacote é muito antiga e preciso da versão que uso neste projeto.

Tentei adicionar na mão e não consegui... consegue me explicar como adicionar de outra forma?

Comment: @LuizNegrini Atualizei a resposta. Veja agora.

Comment: Ainda não aparece nada da forma que falaste... derrepente seria mais interessante implementar na mão... só sei que não aparece nada quando clico no button de confirmar no final do form.

Comment: ótimo, porém toda foto que adiciono ele rejeita. Da o 404 na descrição.

Comment: @LuizNegrini Esqueci de dizer que os métodos são implementados no `HomeController` para este exemplo. Vou alterar novamente a resposta.

Comment: Problema resolvido! Era só eu trocar ali no script o controller e já era hehe! Só queria tirar uma dúvida, é boa prática usar o Request.Files ou mudar a assinatura do método para "HttpFileBase"?

Comment: @LuizNegrini O mais legal é você usar `public HttpPostedFileBase Arquivo { get; set; }` no `Model`. Aí o arquivo vira uma `property` bem mais fácil de ser manipulada.